# Extracting only roads through Overpass API query

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api, python-3, overpass-turbo

I am using overpass API and querying the api for ways,as a result it gives points, whereas I need only lines, multiline strings and polygons. But while using the following code, I get a GeoJSON file and when I load it into QGIS it gives me points and lines, when I switch off the points layer the lines are not loaded onto QGIS. I require only the roads(for which lines, multilines and multipolygons is required) and not Points.

How do I modify the query to get only multilinestrings,lines and multipolygons and not Points?

```
import overpass
import geojson

api = overpass.API()

overpass_url="""

(
  way["highway"="motorway"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
  way["highway"="trunk"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
  way["highway"="primary"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;

"""

res=api.get(overpass_url)


with open("test.geojson",mode="w") as f:
  geojson.dump(res,f)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue after going through little bit of documentation.To fetch only the lines, the following modification to the code can be made.

```
import overpass
import geojson

api = overpass.API()

overpass_url="""

(
  way["highway"="motorway"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
  way["highway"="trunk"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
  way["highway"="primary"](20.8,77.7,21.2,78);
);
out geom;    # change here for only geometry output
"""

res=api.get(overpass_url)


with open("test.geojson",mode="w") as f:
  geojson.dump(res,f)
```

Comment: I got an error when using it like it. I first needed to get the list of features from the feature collection with:  
with open('test.geojson', mode = 'w') as f:
     geojson.dump(res['features'], f)